# css math operators in div text content are getting special treatment

Tags: css, text

This is a boiled down version of a css class im working on:

```
.display {
   overflow: hidden
   white-space: nowrap;
   text-align: right;
   direction: rtl;
}
```

It is supposed to be text that display like a calculator - from right to left.

This works fine when adding numbers to the text content, but any math operator added is added to the left side of the newest string of numbers.

I can't figure out why this happens,im confused why it would have this intricate behaviour, without being specified to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`direction: rtl` specifies the text behavior that you would want for a language that has a right to left flow. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction):

> Use rtl for languages written from right to left (like Hebrew or Arabic)

The `direction` rule takes care of some linguistic characteristics of differenct characters (numbers, word characters, special symbols etc.) that may not be obvious at first.

It for example helps us in the following scenario: Let's say on our website we have:

```html
<h1>
    1 My Headline
</h1>
```

Now let's say our site is multi-languaged and can replace "My Headline" with the corresponding translations of different languages if the user clicks on a button.

Let's assume, "enildaeH yM" is the translation of "My Headline" in some imaginary rtl language (Can't use a real Arabic or Hebrew example because I don't speak it). We can then simply leave the 1 where it is, just translate the actual content for every language and add the right `direction` rule:

```css
.display {
    direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="display">
    1 enildaeH yM
</h1>
```

Note how this keeps the order of the words and just moves the 1 to the (correct) beginning.

In your scenario with the calculator I think using the `direction` rule is the wrong approach, as you don't deal with languages and the complex features of that rule are unwanted here. Maybe `text-align` is already enough for your purpose?

Comment: Alright, seems like i misused it then, didn't know it had a purpose like that. text-align: right doesn't just do it for me, since the overflowing text will still go right. Thanks for the clarification anyways, ill try to find another way.